# What does this ram console error means?

Tags: crash, linux-kernel

I am getting following log in the kernel dmesg. I am not sure why this come. Sometimes my kernel keep rebooting but it does not happen always.

```
<6>[    0.233184] ram_console: got buffer at 42d80000, size 80000
<4>[    0.233184] BUG: Your driver calls ioremap() on system memory.  This leads
<4>[    0.233215] <4>to architecturally unpredictable behaviour on ARMv6+, and ioremap()
<4>[    0.233215] <4>will fail in the next kernel release.  Please fix your driver.
```

Comment: Looks like you call `ioremap()` on system memory. If your code does that, then don't. I very much doubt you'll get any more help without providing some details about what you're doing.

Comment: The error come from machine initialization. msm8x60_init() makes a call to platform_add_devices() and here it fails.